# Is it possibile to access a Hibernate managed DB without Hibernate too?

Tags: java, hibernate

I use Hibernate to manage a DB table and everything works just well.

Now, another system should access the same DB table and I cannot tell it to use Hibernate (because is a monolithic piece of software). 
My doubt concerns the correct usage of the DB from an external software and the consistency problems this approach brings to my attention. In particular, can it be a problem? Maybe Hibernate works in RAM (an ORM can implement caching and lazy transaction to speed up the write/read process) so a possible external transaction onto the DB may bring inconsistency in the Hibernate work. Is this the Hibernate case?

Thank you

Comment: Search Google first - you will find that Hibernate is **not** DB management tool but ORM layer.  
I.e. it does **not** prevent other access to DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers point out, to the database it doesn't matter. However, your application is another matter entirely.
By default Hibernate does not deal nicely with data changes outside of its control. More specifically, it tends to ignore such changes completely.
As a result, the data your application has loaded will quite likely get out of synch with what the database itself knows it to be, leading to all kind of problems. 
That's because Hibernate caches data, a lot of data, and tends to operate on that cache rather than the actual data for increased performance, synchronising with the database only when a transaction is committed. If something else changed the data Hibernate will blissfully ignore those changes and overwrite whatever that other process did, probaly without even giving you a warning.

Comment: Hi jwenting, thank you for your response.
I use Spring's JpaTransactionManager to manage transactions. Can this be a problem for the persistence?

Comment: @gvdm the problem is in the way JPA (which Hibernate implements) handles caching. Once something is in cache it's just assumed to always be in synch with the database. Only way around that afaik is to configure JPA/Hibernate to not use a cache. This of course affects performance, but if there are multiple avenues of changes to the RDBMS it's the only way.

Comment: So I should look for the way to disable Hibernate's caching, right?

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely doesn't matter how are you accessing the DB (either through ORM, JDBC or some other connector), only thing that does matter is how your DB will handle multiple connections by different systems (so you might want to take a look at stuff like [Transaction isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)).

Comment: yes and no. Many ORM tools by default cache a lot of data for faster access, causing conflicts to go unnoticed at application level until there's a constraint violation trying to write something.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, your answer is certainly better :)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't. You'd better do some integration-test.

1. Database has another layer of consistency guarantee.
2. Hibernate should deal with its caching 'correctly'.